# Расчёт мультиноминальной логистической регрессии в R

Tags: r, статистика

Овладеваю R, но в кратчайшие сроки нужно провести то, что указано в заголовке. Английский находится на той же стадии, что и R, поэтому и спрашиваю на русскоязычном варианте.

Собственно, прошу пояснить мне, как делать истинно верно мультиноминальную регрессию.

Почитал help("mlogit"), но всё же не выходит. Пока что команда выглядит так:

> mlogit(Konfessiya ~ ProizvolnyeUmozaklyucheniya + Sverkhobobschenie + IzbiratelnoeAbstragirovanie + PreuvelicheniePreumenshenie + Personalizatsiya + Dikhotomiya + Dolzhenstvovanie + Predskazyvanie + CHtenieMyslej + NakleivanieYArlykov + StatusKvo, data = RegressionReligion, shape="wide", choice="mode")

После чего R выдаёт мне ошибку:

> Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
>     system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.34803e-32

Заранее благодарен каждому ответившему.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow на русском!

Comment: Пропущенные значения в датасете есть?

Comment: @ArtemKlevstov Нет, весь датасет целый. Сделал с помощью multinom, поигрался с откидыванием незначимых переменных, дошёл по критерию Акаике с 1.000.000 до 627, но из 427 испытуемых верно определились только 268 испытуемых. Не понимаю, что происходит.

Comment: А откуда уверенность, что 268 из 427 - это плохо?

Comment: А это не плохо?